# Is docstring being declared every time the function is called?

Tags: python, programming-languages

The Python official document specifies that a docstring is a string literal that occurs at the beginning of a function. And it can be accessed using the `__doc__` attribute.

If I have a function that will be called many many times, does that mean the docstring will be declared every time the function is called?

If this is the case, would it be more efficient to design docstring in such a way that it is stored in `__doc__` but not being declared every time the function is called?

Comment: Answering the question in your title: no. When you run a Python file (or import one) all the classes and functions are parsed, "compiled" to byte code, and memory is allocated. A docstring being redeclared everytime a function is called or class instantiated would frankly be a terrible design decision!

Comment: How would the string be accessible via the `__doc__` attribute *outside the function* if it would be redeclared every time the function runs (and thus presumably also discarded at the end)? Leave such micro-optimisation concerns up to Python and assume that it does something sensible, unless you have clear proof that it's an issue worth worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

- every time you start a python program, they are "important" into memory only "once", parsed so that every "object" properties are determined and all objects are put into their separate memory locations and then linked together in the memory to make it a whole running system (remember the object nature of python).
- second behavior is when you don't restrict the python interpreter. If you `import` your files, then, in addition to the above steps, it writes these objects into more durable `.pyc` files under `__pycache__` folder at the same level of the file.

In this process, new objects are created to have a `__doc__` property object when certain keywords are parsed, mainly `class` and `def`. These `__doc__` of each are then either kept empty, filled some default by inheritance, or if it has a docstring then it is written inside.

You can see this behavior on different objects, created with/out supplying a docstring, simply by using `dir(objectname)`. To answer your question, you can use this command throughout your program.

**However**, this is true only for static written code. If you are trying to make objects on the fly, especially within loops, then your objects will be actively created and destroyed, thus there will be almost no optimization against them and docstrings will be created again and again.

consider these two:

```py
def staticMethod():
 pass

for i in range(5):
 def activeMethod():
  pass
 print(staticMethod,"s")
 print(activeMethod,"a")
```

while `staticMethod` is served from the same memory location, the memory address for `activeMethod` changes. you will see an altering between few values because python can still optimize since this one is a simple example.

So keep yourself aware of this distinct behavior, especially of loops.